# add values from one column if criteria met in another column R

Tags: r, dataframe, conditional-statements, sum

So i've created a summarised data frame from a larger df which i want to use to calculate percentages.

```
tibble::tribble(
  ~Year, ~Rider_Class, ~yearly_transactions,
   2021,     "casual",             2528702L,
   2021,     "member",             3065797L,
   2022,     "casual",             2321824L,
   2022,     "member",             3345462L
)
```

my goal is to get the total of both categories of rider class from each year, then divide that by each rider class to get my percentages, but I'm struggling with how to calculate the sum of transactions based on the conditions in the "year" column.

based on some reading, I attempted this code:

```
sum (Transactions_per_Year[which(Transactions_per_Year$Year == "2021"),Transactions_per_Year$yearly_transactions]
```

but my end result was

Error: Incomplete expression: sum (Transactions_per_Year[which(Transactions_per_Year$Year == "2021"),Transactions_per_Year$yearly_transactions]

Comment: You need a group by sum `aggregate(yearly_transactions ~ Year, Transactions_per_Year, sum)` or with `dplyr` - `Transactions_per_Year %>% reframe(year_transactions = sum(yearly_transactions), .by = Year)`

Comment: they gets me part of the way there. how can i use those results for a calculation? Example: dividing the rider class totals by total transactions to get a percentage based on rider class?

Comment: If you meant the proportions `Transactions_per_Year %>% mutate(prop = proportions(yearly_transactions), .by = Year)` or `Transactions_per_Year %>% mutate(prop = yearly_transactions/sum(yearly_transactions), .by = Year)` would work

Comment: Your code is actually doing the yearly subset.  If you want it by Rider_class, the grouping should be on that `Transactions_per_Year %>% mutate(prop = yearly_transactions/sum(yearly_transactions), .by = Rider_Class)`

Comment: I tried running that code, adding a label for a new frame Percentages_per_Year<- Transactions_per_Year %>% 
  mutate(prop = yearly_transactions/sum(yearly_transactions), .by = Rider_Class)
``` got the following error: Error in `mutate()`:
! Can't supply `.by` when `.data` is a grouped data frame.
Backtrace:
 1. Transactions_per_Year %>% ...
 3. dplyr:::mutate.data.frame(., prop = yearly_transactions/sum(yearly_transactions), .by = Rider_Class)

Comment: What is the error.  I assume you have a dplyr version of `1.1.0` i.e. the recent version or else you have to do `Transactions_per_Year %>% group_by(Year) %>% mutate(prop = yearly_transactions/sum(yearly_transactions)) %>% ungroup`

Comment: edited the above comment to add the error text. dplyr is running 1.1.0

Comment: That error seems to be a result of already grouped data.  You may try the edited  code above or ungroup before the mutate i.e. `Transactions_per_Year  %>% ungroup %>% mutate(prop = yearly_transactions/sum(yearly_transactions), .by = Rider_Class)`

Comment: wouldn't that sum up all transactions then? The issue is totaling the transactions by year, then dividing by the rider class subset to get a percentage for each year

Comment: If you want to sum by year, change the `.by = Rider_Class` to `.by = Year` as it is not clear what you r expected percentage is

Comment: i.e. I get these values as percentage `Transactions_per_Year %>% mutate(prop = yearly_transactions/sum(yearly_transactions), .by = Year) %>% pull(prop)#
[1] 0.4519979 0.5480021 0.4096889 0.5903111`

Comment: that's what it looks like on my end too. as you can tell I'm pretty new at this. thanks so much for your patience.

Comment: It's okay.  I was just confused by the logic you wanted to divide.  I guess this should solve your problem

Comment: looks good to go! thank you for your help! If I save this as a frame and format the prop column to a percent, this should visualize in ggplot2 pretty easily